# ionic app icon and splashscreen shows cordova default icon inspite of successfully running ionic resources command

Tags: ionic-framework

ionic info

Your system information:

ordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v6.9.1
Xcode version: Not installed

Config.xml

tutorialApp
        
            An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
        
        
            Your Name Here

Comment: hi..it show the default only for IOS or also for Android?

Comment: i have checked only on android

Comment: can you post your config.xml file?

Comment: unable to add it in comments so edited the question and added config.xml in it

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to a known problem with Cordova Android platform 6.0.0. Try to force update to the latest version of Android platform:

```
cordova platform update android@6.1.0
```

EDIT:

Cordova 6.5.0 has been released recently. This release updates cordova-android to version 6.1.1. So best solution now is:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Answer (score 0):

First verify the resources folder inside your app's folder to assure the icons and splashes are the ones you want and that the command run correctly.
If they are OK, happens a lot that you need to remove the platforms and re-add them again for those changes to refresh:

```
$ ionic platform rm android
$ ionic platform add android
```

Or maybe a state reset is enough:

```
$ ionic state reset
```